# joining tests from multiple files with mocha.js

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm trying to join all the tests from multiple files in one file, something like this:

```
  describe('Controllers', function() {
    describe('messages.js', function() {
      require('./controllertests/messages').test(options);
    })
    describe('users.js', function() {
      require('./controllertests/users').test(options);
    })
  })
```

I'm pretty sure this is not the best way to join tests, I'm having some dificulty finding examples of how to do this :s

Comment: Curious, why do the tests need to be joined together in one file?

Comment: For sharing local variables and organization

Comment: It might make more sense if you include the tests into the question. It sounds like you might be leaning towards integration tests (as opposed to unit tests). Generally you shouldn't need to share variables across tests.

Comment: I guess unit tests is not the best term in fact, API tests might be more correct

Comment: And the big issue is that I would prefer to have like 20 files than 1 huuuuge file

Comment: Also, if you look at how Mocha handles suites with the concept of `.only()` it might be useful to be able to put `describe.only()` to still run a whole directory of tests.  That's what brought me here.

Comment: I agree with @Chris, Mocha gives you other tools to solve this problem. You are inventing your own here. And indeed like Chris says you will have trouble if you would want to run only one or a few test (with mocha --grep, mocha command line) because their require will be only in the top most js.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

If you want to include multiple modules *into* your `describe` hierarchy like you are doing in your question, what you are doing is pretty much *it*, unless you want to write a custom test loader for Mocha. Writing the custom loader would not be easier or make your code clearer than what you already have.

Here's an example of how I would change a few things. The `test` subdirectory in this example is organized as:

```
.
└── test
    ├── a
    │   └── a.js
    ├── b
    │   └── b.js
    ├── common.js
    └── top.js
```

`top.js`:

```
function importTest(name, path) {
    describe(name, function () {
        require(path);
    });
}

var common = require("./common");

describe("top", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
       console.log("running something before each test");
    });
    importTest("a", './a/a');
    importTest("b", './b/b');
    after(function () {
        console.log("after all tests");
    });
});
```

The `importTest` function is just to show how it would be possible to handle the repetition of importing multiple modules without having to retype the whole `describe(... require...` thing every single time. The `common` module is meant to hold what you need to use in multiple modules of the test suite. I'm not actually using it in `top` but it could be used there, if needed.

I will note here that the `beforeEach` will run its code before each and every single test registered with `it` whether they appear inside the `describe` in `top` or they appear in *any of the modules imported*. With `--recursive`, the `beforeEach` code would have to be copied into each module or perhaps you'd have a `beforeEach` hook in each module that calls a function imported from a common module.

Also, the `after` hook will run after **all** tests in the suite. This cannot be replicated with `--recursive`. If you use `--recursive` and add the code of `after` to each module, it will be executed once per module rather than just once for the *whole* test.

Having all tests appear under a single `top` heading cannot be replicated by using `--recursive`. With `--recursive` each file could have `describe("top"` but this would create a new `top` heading for each file.

`common.js`:

```
var chai = require("chai");

var options = {
    foo: "foo"
};

exports.options = options;
exports.chai = chai;
exports.assert = chai.assert;
```

Using a *module* named `common` like this is something I've done in some of my test suites to avoid having to `require` a bunch of stuff over and over and to hold global **read-only** variables or functions that don't keep state. I prefer not to pollute the `global` object like in thgaskell's answer because this object is truly global and accessible even in third party libraries your code may be loading. This is not something I find acceptable in my code.

`a/a.js`:

```
var common = require("../common");
var options = common.options;
var assert = common.assert;

it("blah a", function () {
    console.log(options.foo);
    assert.isTrue(false);
});
```

`b/b.js`:

```
it("blah b", function () {});
```

Comment: While I agree that you should not pollute `global` scope, I use this for the assertion libraries to keep the test files cleaner. It's not like you're overwriting `global.process`. Local variables will override `global` unless other libraries are explicitly calling `global.XYZ` which is unlikely. It only lasts for the duration of the tests. Hasn't hurt me yet, but I'll let you know the moment it bites me in the ass :)

Comment: What is the difference between `importTest` and calling `require('path')()` for example?

Comment: @CreasolDev The `importTest` function is just a convenience function. The important thing it does is wrap the `require` call in a `describe` block. It is important that the `require` call be wrapped in `describe` otherwise the modules won't be isolated in their own block and any hook set by the imported file will be set on the wrong block. If `importTest` was replaced with a direct call to `require` without a wrapping `describe`, then the modules `a/a` and `b/b` would share hooks. For instance, a `beforeEach` hook set in `b/b` would also run before each test in `a/a`.

Comment: Do note that *dynamic require* (like what you are doing with `require(path)` where `path` is a variable) is not recommended, because it does not mesh well with tools like webpack that need to be able to statically analyze require calls. Instead it's better to accept a function i.s.o a path and call require inside the function. With arrow functions that's also pretty neat.

Comment: I would NOT run any logic such as beforeEach in your top level describe.  Let each file do its own beforeEach "stuff".  You will be coupling your tests to each other and unrelated implementation if you do this.

Comment: I'd also do the wrapping of describes in their respective files, not in the importTest function.  Top level describes in each respective file should be describing their test suites purpose anyway

Answer (score 38):

Although this may not be directly linked to the question, the answer I was looking for was:

```
$ mocha --recursive
```

Will execute all tests in sub directories of the "test" folder. Neat. Saves having to maintain a list of tests that I want to load and actually just always run everything.

Comment: Best answer! Far simpler than other proposed solutions.

Comment: @caiosm1005 This answer is not actually solving *the problem presented by the OP*. Sure, *if you do not need to do what the OP wants to do*, then you should be using this. However, if you want to wrap each test file in multiple `describe` blocks, `describe` blocks that span files, `--recursive` won't do it. Seeing as it does not solve the OP's problem, I would not call it "best".

Comment: @louis - I believe you can wrap each separate file in `describe` blocks

Comment: @IanJamieson The OP is trying to have *multiple files* covered by a *single* `describe` block. Look at the question. The "Controllers" `describe` block  should encompass the tests of `./controllertests/messages.js` and `./controllertests/users.js`. Slapping `--recursive` onto a Mocha invocation does not magically create a `describe("Controllers"` block.

Comment: @Louis Just trying to help. Sorry if I offended you by trying to magically create `describe` blocks - which I actually learnt to do from Dumbledore himself.

Comment: This is also what I was looking for. Thank you.

I am using: mocha --exit --recursive ./*.tests.js

Answer (score 16):

There's nothing that prevents you from running multiple test files. Generally, each test should not be dependent on the results of another test, so sharing variables isn't something you'd want to do.

Here's an example of how you could organize your test files.

```
.
├── app.js
└── test
    ├── common.js
    ├── mocha.opts
    │
    ├── controllers
    │   ├── messages-controller.js
    │   └── users-controller.js
    │
    └── models
        ├── messages-model.js
        └── users-model.js
```

Then inside of your `mocha.opts` file, make sure to set the `--recursive` option.

**mocha.opts**

```
--ui bdd
--recursive
```

If there *are* common modules that you want to include across all files, you can add that to the `common.js` file. Files at the root of the `test` directory will run before files in nested directories.

**common.js**

```
global.chai = require('chai');
global.assert = chai.assert;
global.expect = chai.expect;
chai.should();
chai.config.includeStack = true;

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

// Include common modules from your application that will be used among multiple test suites.
global.myModule = require('../app/myModule');
```

Comment: Would anyone mind adding code for files in the controllers and models directories?  It would be great to have a full example.

Comment: @Gavin - these will just be test suits so they would contain `describe('mytest', function() { /* ..... etc */ });`

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old post but I wanted to chime in with what has been a good solution to me, very similar to the method proposed by OP.

The project I'm working on is well tested and the tests keep growing. I ended up using `require` because it is synchronous and therefore makes it a bit easier to compose your tests without too much change in architecture:

```
// inside test/index.js

describe('V1 ROUTES', () => {
  require('./controllers/claims.test');
  require('./controllers/claimDocuments.test');
  require('./controllers/claimPhotos.test');
  require('./controllers/inspections.test');
  require('./controllers/inspectionPhotos.test');
  require('./controllers/versions.test');
  require('./services/login.v1.test');
});

describe('V2 ROUTES', () => {
  require('./services/login.v2.test');
  require('./services/dec-image.v2.test');
});

describe('V3 ROUTES', () => {
  require('./services/login.v3.test');
  require('./services/getInspectionPhotosv3.test');
  require('./services/getPolicyInfo.v3.test');
});

describe('ACTIONS', () => {
  require('./actions/notifications.test');
});
```

Comment: What do your actual test files look like? eg. claims.text

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem where I had bunch of tests for classes in the same category and I wanted to group them together to make viewing them in an IDE easier. All of my tests and code were already using ES6 modules - I didn't want to rewrite all of them to use `require` like I saw in other examples.

I solved it by having my "grouping" `describe` exported, and then importing it into my test files and programmatically adding them to the imported `describe`.  I ended up creating a helper method to abstract away all of the plumbing.

**In someCategory.spec.js**

```
const someCategory= describe("someCategory", () => {});


// Use this just like a regular `describe` to create a child of this scope in another file
export default function describeMember(skillName, testFn) {
  describe(skillName, function configureContext() {
    // Make context a child of `someCategory` context
    function Context() {}
    Context.prototype = someCategory.ctx;
    this.ctx = new Context();
    // Re-parent the suite created by `describe` above (defaults to root scope of file it was created in)
    this.parent.suites.pop();
    someCategory.addSuite(this);
    // Invoke the fn now that we've properly set up the parent/context
    testFn.call(this);
  });
}
```

**In individual tests:**

```
import { default as describeCategoryMember } from './someCategory.spec';

describeCategoryMember('something', () => {
    describe('somethingElse', () => {
        ...
    });

    it('a test', () => {
        ...
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to run all the files that end with _test.js in the **tests** folder (if it doesnt work be sure to check that you are doing it on ./tests folder)

```
 "scripts": {
  "test": "find ./tests -name '*_test.js' | xargs mocha -R spec"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// apple.test.js
import internalTests from './internalTests.js'

describe.only('[---- Apple ----]', () => {
    const search = 'german'
    internalTests(search)

    describe('searchVideo', () => {
        it('should search videos with specific params', async() => {
            // ..
        })
    })
}




// internalTests.js
const internalTests = search => {
    describe('[---- Internal DB ----]', () => {
        describe('_validateCfg', () => {
            it('should throw error because params are not valid', async() => {
                // console.log(search)
            })
        })
    })
}

export default internalTests
```

Answer (score -11):

```
describe( 'Running automation test, Please wait for all test to complete!'.red, function () {


    var run = require( './Test.js' );

    for ( var i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {
        run.badLogin();
        run.loginLimited();
        run.acceptJob();
        run.drivingToJob();
        run.arrivedAtJob();
        run.towingJob();
        run.arrivedDestination();
        run.jobComplete();
        run.restrictionLicensePlate();
        run.newNodeMainMenu();
        run.newNodeMainMenuToDrafts();
        run.draftDelete();
        run.resetAllData();
        run.companyVehicle();
        run.actionsScreenClockInOut();
        run.mainMenuLogout();
        run.loginAdmin();
        run.actionsScreenLogout();
    }
} );
```

Comment: It is best to add a description along with the code so that others can determine whether this is an acceptable answer.

Comment: Why the loop? What is in `./Test.js`? Who knows? For the record, I'm currently the top answerer in the [tag:mocha] tag. I know Mocha inside and out but I cannot make sense of this answer.

Comment: @Louis seems like he wanted to run the tests *n* times using the loop.